Touchpad was not deteced
After installation ubuntu 20.04.6, my touchpad cannot work. I tried with cat /proc/bus/input/devices, touchpad cannot be detected, you can find the results in the following:
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0003 Version=0000
N: Name="Sleep Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0E/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=4000 0 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0001 Version=0000
N: Name="Power Button"
P: Phys=PNP0C0C/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event1 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=10000000000000 0

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0005 Version=0000
N: Name="Lid Switch"
P: Phys=PNP0C0D/button/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:01/input/input2
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event2 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=1

I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=ab83
N: Name="AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input3
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event3 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=120013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
B: LED=7

I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="Intel HID events"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/INTC1078:00/input/input4
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event4 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=81000300000000 5000004000 1e294000000020 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=1bcf Product=0005 Version=0110
N: Name="USB Optical Mouse"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1BCF:0005.0001/input/input5
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=17
B: KEY=1f0000 0 0 0 0
B: REL=1943
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=2b7e Product=c664 Version=0009
N: Name="FHD Webcam: FHD Webcam"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event6 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=048d Product=5000 Version=0110
N: Name="ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8176) Keyboard"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:048D:5000.0003/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event7 leds 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=12001f
B: KEY=306ff 0 0 483ffff17aff32d bfd4444600000000 1 130c730b17c007 ffbf7bfad941dfff febeffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: REL=1040
B: ABS=100000000
B: MSC=10
B: LED=1f

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=048d Product=5000 Version=0110
N: Name="ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8176) Wireless Radio Control"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:048D:5000.0003/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=rfkill kbd event8 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=13
B: KEY=80000000000000 0 0 0
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0003 Vendor=2b7e Product=c664 Version=0009
N: Name="FHD Webcam: IR Camera"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-5/button
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.2/input/input9
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event9 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=3
B: KEY=100000 0 0 0

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event10 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event11 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event12 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input13
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event13 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event14 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event15 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=140

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Mic"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input16
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event16 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="HDA Intel PCH Headphone"
P: Phys=ALSA
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input17
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event17 
B: PROP=0
B: EV=21
B: SW=4

There's also one error message for dmesg
[    4.384998] systemd-journald[565]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[    4.389104] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    4.390189] usbhid 1-6:1.0: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[    4.393772] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.393782] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    4.393783] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.393785] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.393786] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.393788] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    4.393917] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    4.398198] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    4.400632] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2020.42 buildtype 1 build 15791
[    4.402465] usb 1-5: Found UVC 1.50 device FHD Webcam (2b7e:c664)
[    4.402916] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-0041-0041.sfi
[    4.402927] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x100800
[    4.402928] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 175-42.20
[    4.402929] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[    4.404705] usbhid 1-10:1.0: couldn't find an input interrupt endpoint
[    4.410110] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    4.410113] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    4.420794] input: Intel HID events as /devices/platform/INTC1078:00/input/input4
[    4.421466] intel-hid INTC1078:00: failed to enable HID power button
[    4.439421] input: USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.0/0003:1BCF:0005.0001/input/input5
[    4.445336] hid-generic 0003:1BCF:0005.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input0
[    4.447414] input: FHD Webcam: FHD Webcam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/input/input6
[    4.450692] usb 1-5: Found UVC 1.50 device FHD Webcam (2b7e:c664)
[    4.452821] hid-generic 0003:048D:6010.0002: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8291)] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input1
[    4.457784] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8176) Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:048D:5000.0003/input/input7
[    4.464592] input: FHD Webcam: IR Camera as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.2/input/input9
[    4.468442] mei_me 0000:00:16.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.474600] Bluetooth: hci0: MSFT filter_enable is already on
[    4.484008] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    4.484108] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'wens: 61c038651aabdcf94bd0ac7ff06c7248db18c600'
[    4.484192] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    4.489999] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[    4.514453] input: ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8176) Wireless Radio Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/0003:048D:5000.0003/input/input8
[    4.514559] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[    4.514612] hid-generic 0003:048D:5000.0003: input,hiddev1,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8176)] on usb-0000:00:14.0-8/input0
[    4.514726] hid-generic 0003:048D:CE00.0004: hiddev2,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Device [ITE Tech. Inc. ITE Device(8291)] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input1
[    4.595252] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.
[    4.595388] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled
[    4.660781] asus_wmi: ASUS WMI generic driver loaded
[    4.665376] asus_wmi: ASUS Management GUID not found
[    4.666588] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    4.667755] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.716397] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    4.716420] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.63.2.2
[    4.716813] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 66.f1c864e0.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-66.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    4.740749] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    4.740772] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.741020] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    4.741057] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
[    4.741061] snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
[    4.743279] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1p4): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    4.746957] ACPI Warning: \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20210730/nsarguments-61)
[    4.747113] pci 0000:01:00.0: optimus capabilities: enabled, status dynamic power, hda bios codec supported
[    4.747117] VGA switcheroo: detected Optimus DSM method \_SB_.PC00.PEG1.PEGP handle
[    4.747118] nouveau: detected PR support, will not use DSM
[    4.747144] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    4.747230] nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (193000a1)
[    4.749379] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    4.749381] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    4.749382] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    4.749725] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1p1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    4.750116] Adding 255999996k swap on /dev/nvme1n1p2.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:255999996k SSFS
[    4.756050] EXT4-fs (nvme1n1p6): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    4.760606] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input10
[    4.760626] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input11
[    4.760648] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input12
[    4.760690] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input13
[    4.760731] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
[    4.760759] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
[    4.766766] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    4.769623] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.044:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-senddoc" pid=1001 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.769683] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.044:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="lsb_release" pid=1017 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.769742] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.044:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="ippusbxd" pid=1007 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.769875] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.044:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-xpdfimport" pid=1000 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.770247] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.044:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="libreoffice-oopslash" pid=1010 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.770364] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.048:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=1014 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.770368] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.048:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=1014 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.770615] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.048:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/man" pid=1002 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.770616] audit: type=1400 audit(1727354943.048:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="man_filter" pid=1002 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    4.773726] thermal thermal_zone3: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[    4.928257] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded PNVM version 0x5a8dfca
[    4.939899] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    4.969942] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    4.969944] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    4.969946] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    4.972309] NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
[    5.010525] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 4c:b0:4a:7e:4d:de
[    5.030145] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[    5.106455] RTL8226B_RTL8221B 2.5Gbps PHY r8169-0-2d00:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-2d00:00, irq=MAC)


